# Creating button with Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am creating a button with three divs. first div has leftcorner image, second div which is in the middle has a image which is stretched depends on the text width and then the right div having rightcorner image.

This is how it is made

[image: Sample button]

This is the [JsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/a19fm2hn/6/) i am trying to create a button. but the div are not showing correctly. If i simple put images together without divs then i can see the images. Can anyone tell me how can i make a button with three divs? I am not a front end developer but this thing came up in my project and i have to work on this one. Thanks

```
<div class="container" >

        <div  id='leftdiv'><img src="http://i.share.pho.to/ff6cc4e3_o.png"></div>
        <div  id='backgrounddiv'>Click me<img src="http://i.share.pho.to/0ffe9c14_o.png"></div>
        <div  id='rightdiv'><img src="http://i.share.pho.to/245be416_o.png"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: But if you want it to show.. then why is the visibility set to hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your css and use image background for middle div which has text

```
#container{
  display:inline-block;
}
#leftdiv{
  float:left;
}
#backgrounddiv{
  background:url("http://i.share.pho.to/0ffe9c14_o.png") top center repeat-x;
  float:left;
  height:70px;
  padding:10px;
  line-height:70px;
}
#rightdiv{
   float:left;
}
```

please refer the fixed code : http://jsbin.com/tuzipiyupo/4/edit

Comment: but i want to make it a button it is not clickable how can i make it a clickable button?

Comment: can it be clickeable? this one is perfect but it is not clickable can it be clickable or not?

Comment: You can make it clickable by adding a tab around container

Comment: or you can use jquery or javascript to bind click event

Comment: when i am copying the JS bin code then it is not working the way it is showing in the Js Bin Output screen

Comment: Thanks PRAH but both JsFiddle and JS BIn showing the correct result but when i am trying in my local browser in wamp server i am getting this output http://i.share.pho.to/5cdbfb89_o.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `style="visibility:hidden"` from `<div class="container" style="visibility:hidden">`

This will hide your div.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a19fm2hn/11/) here.

**Edit:**

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="button">

   <div  id='leftdiv'><img src="http://i.share.pho.to/ff6cc4e3_o.png"/></div>
    <div  id='backgrounddiv'>CLick Me </div>
    <div  id='rightdiv'><img src="http://i.share.pho.to/245be416_o.png"/></div>

    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
  display:inline-block;
}


#leftdiv{
  float:left;
}
#backgrounddiv{
  background:url("http://i.share.pho.to/0ffe9c14_o.png") top center repeat-x;
  float:left;
  height:70px;
  padding:10px;
  line-height:70px;
}
#rightdiv{
   float:left;
}
```

**Script**

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
    alert("click");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a19fm2hn/9/

Comment: sorry i explained wrongly it is showing but not correct can you check my updated fiddle link

Comment: @user3754676 check updated JSFiddle with click event.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

> style="visibility:hidden"

line from parent div.Why do you use the div for button functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi I have updated your code Here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/Maheshkonduru/a19fm2hn/10/

Css
#backgrounddiv{
  background:url("http://i.share.pho.to/0ffe9c14_o.png") top center repeat-x;
  height:70px;
  padding:10px;
  line-height:70px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.container > div {
    float: left;
    display:block
}

#leftdiv {

    float: left;
    width: 25px;
}

HTML
<div class="container">       
        <div  id='leftdiv'><img src="http://i.share.pho.to/ff6cc4e3_o.png"></div>
        <div  id='backgrounddiv'>Click me</div>
        <div  id='rightdiv'><img src="http://i.share.pho.to/245be416_o.png"></div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you've already (at the time of writing) accepted another answer, I'd suggest the following approach instead (if you *must* use images):

```css
button {
  width: 500px;
  /* using the 'main' background as the background-image: */
  background-image: url(http://i.share.pho.to/0ffe9c14_o.png);
  /* repeating horizontally */
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  /* removing the default border, padding and margin: */
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /* setting the line-height, and height, equal to the
     the height of the images we're using, to vertically
     center the text within the button: */
  line-height: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

/* using CSS pseudo-elements to insert the left, and
   right, images: */
button::before {
  content: url(http://i.share.pho.to/ff6cc4e3_o.png);
  float: left;
}
button::after {
  content: url(http://i.share.pho.to/245be416_o.png);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<button>Click here</button>
```